# c function returns two pointers with different types

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

My function should return 2 pointers to different structures.

```
struct a {
   ...
};

struct b{
   ...
};
```

The 2 options that I see for my functioin are:

#### 1

```
void myFunction(struct a *s_a, struct_b *s_b){
    s_a = &a;
    s_b = &b;
    do something with s_a and s_b;
```

};

#### 2

```
struct c{
  *a...;
  *b...;
}
 
struct c myFunction(){
   ...
   return c
}
```

Are these options correct? Which is better? why?

Thank you!

P.S. I couldn't find answers to this question out there. I am sure the answer is camouflaged in a different question but I couldn't spot it.

Disclamer: I am actually using typedef and not struct. That's why I mention 2 different types.

Comment: What is `myFunction` really supposed to do? To initialize the structures? What is the actual and underlying problem you need to solve? Why do you think that "returning" two structures would solve that problem?

Comment: This is not a trivial question to answer.  It depends on what set of trade-offs are more acceptable in a particular set of use cases.

Comment: What does `void myFunction(&a,&b)` mean in C? In C++ it's passing two structures by reference, but I haven't seen that syntax in C.

Comment: @AdrianMole is the same as what you describe for C++

Comment: He probably meant `void myFunction(struct a*..., struct b*...){...}`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude. Yes, myFunction should initialize the structures. Both structures are inter-dependent (these are hash tables filled with data from same input from stdin). I couldn't find a way to have a single structure and 2 structures is the best option that I found so far (considering my humble C skills).

Comment: Then the common way is to just pass pointers to the structures as arguments, and initialize the structures as you would do it without calling a function.

Comment: Are your functions to return new/modified pointers? Or just pointers to structures that are already known to the calling module? If the former, then your first version needs *double pointers* as its arguments `void myFunction(AType **a, BType **b)`. (Note: C doesn't do references, in the sense they are used in C++.)

Comment: The question is opinion based. Each option is correct. Which one is better is up to you.

Comment: `void myFunction(&a,&b){...};` isn't valid C. Is this question mistagged?

Comment: @ikegami it's my mistake. I tried to simplify and show only the idea and ended up making it wrong. I also don't have enough experience with C and make too many basic mistakes. Thanks a lot for your answer, it helped me a lot!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first of your options doesn't return pointers as desired.

Say you have

```c
typedef struct { ... } StructA;
typedef struct { ... } StructB;
```

The following is commonly used:

```c
void myFunction(StructA **aptr, StructA **bptr) {
   StructA *a = malloc(sizeof(StructA));
   StructB *b = malloc(sizeof(StructB));

   ... do stuff with a and b ...

   *aptr = a;
   *bptr = b;
}

void caller(void) {
   StructA *a;
   StructB *b;
   myFunction(&a, &b);
   ...
}
```

or

```c
void myFunction(StructA **aptr, StructA **bptr) {
   *aptr = malloc(sizeof(StructA));
   *bptr = malloc(sizeof(StructB));

   ... do stuff with *aptr and *bptr ...
}

void caller(void) {
   StructA *a;
   StructB *b;
   myFunction(&a, &b);
   ...
}
```

---

But yes, you could use a struct as a return value.

```c
typedef struct {
   StructA *a;
   StructB *b;
} StructAB;

StructAB myFunction(void) {
   StructA *a = malloc(sizeof(StructA));
   StructB *b = malloc(sizeof(StructB));

   ... do stuff with a and b ...

   return (StructAB){ .a = a, .b = b };
}

void caller(void) {
   StructAB ab = myFunction();
   StructA *a = ab.a;
   StructB *b = ab.b;
   ...
}
```

It's a bit more complicated, but not extremely so.

Comment: Whoa! Never return pointers to static function variables! That used to be a thing people did. Before threads. These days that is just asking for someone to call your function from two threads and blow up their world.

Comment: `myFunction` can just return `struct AB`, there is no need to dynamically allocate a return value or introduce lifetime management

Comment: @M.M, *sigh*, I knew that. I was going to used that. I took a wrong turn somewhere. Answer updated.

Comment: @ikegami something like `return (StructAB){ .a = a, .b = b };` I believe.

Comment: @isrnick, Thought so, but was unable to test/check earlier. Thanks.